# Slider Bar Only Spot On Certain Number

Tags: python-2.7, slider, tkinter

Here is my slider bar, I am wondering is there a way to limit the numbers the slider can be spot on,(only on 1500, 1200, 900, 600)

```
slider = 
Tkinter.Scale(frame,orient="vertical",length=300,width=20,sliderlength=10,
from_=1500,to=600,tickinterval=300)
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `resolution` parameter for that.

```
import Tkinter

root = Tkinter.Tk()

slider = Tkinter.Scale(length=300, showvalue=False,
        from_=1500, to=600, tickinterval=300, resolution=300)
slider.grid(padx=12, pady=12)

root.mainloop()
```